# How do you match a string with nested brackets among other bracketed strings?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a log file that I'm try to pull a specific section from:

```
[2020][159]Debugging: [FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]][PRODUCTION1] - [192.0.0.1] - [Mozilla]
[2021][532]Debugging: [FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple][PRODUCTION2] - [192.0.0.32] - [Chrome]
```

I need to get `FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]` and `FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple`

The `"FIXED_"` part will *always be the same*.

I tried using something simple like `\[FIXED.*]\]` but that only worked on the top line.

Comment: Try `@"FIXED.*?(?=\]\[)"` pattern

Comment: Yes! That worked!  You should make it an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `@"FIXED.*?(?=\]\[)"` pattern:

```
 FIXED  - fixed part
 .*?    - zero or more arbitrary characters (as few as posible)
 ][     - followed by ][ (but not included into the match)
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "[2020][159]Debugging: [FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]][PRODUCTION1] - [192.0.0.1] - [Mozilla]",
    "[2021][532]Debugging: [FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple][PRODUCTION2] - [192.0.0.32] - [Chrome]",
  };

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"FIXED.*?(?=\]\[)");

  var result = tests
    .Select(test => regex.Match(test))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => match.Value);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]
FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple
```

**Edit:** In case we want to *count* opening and closing brackets we have to use a more elaborated pattern, e.g.

```
 @"FIXED(?:.*?(?<o>\[)?.*?(?<-o>\])?.*?)*(?=\])"
```

here `(?<o>\[)` and `(?<-o>\])` are *balancing groups* to match *opening* and corresponding *closing* brackets:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "[2020][159]Debugging: [FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]][PRODUCTION1] - [192.0.0.1] - [Mozilla]",
    "[2021][532]Debugging: [FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple][PRODUCTION2] - [192.0.0.32] - [Chrome]",
    "[2021][532]Debugging: [FIXED_XYZ_02 - [Some][Text]][PRODUCTION2] - [192.0.0.32] - [Chrome]",
    "[2021][532]Debugging: [FIXED_XYZ_02 - [Some][Text] more][PRODUCTION2] - [192.0.0.32] - [Chrome]",
  };

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"FIXED(?:.*?(?<o>\[)?.*?(?<-o>\])?.*?)*(?=\])");

  var result = tests
    .Select(test => regex.Match(test))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => match.Value);

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
FIXED_RANDOM_324 - Some Text[R] Here[TM]
FIXED_ABCDEF_21 - Simple
FIXED_XYZ_02 - [Some][Text]
FIXED_XYZ_02 - [Some][Text] more
```

Comment: But it won't handle situation where `]` isn't followed directly by `[`

Comment: Now that you mention it, `FIXED_XYZ_02 - [Some][Text]` won't match properly, but fortunately for me, it will adequately handle 99.9% of the cases.

Comment: @Kcoder: I see; if `[Some][Text]`and alike constructions are the problem, we need a more elaborated pattern; we typically use *blancing groups* for this, i.e. we match closing ']' for every opeing `[`. Please, see my edit